# Migrate MySQL DB tables/data from local to production server Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, orm, database-migration, laravel-5.6

What I want to do is migrate my tables and data from phpmyadmin/MySQL from a local server to a production server.

For example if I was on my local and I made a change to the database how would I also push those changes to the production server/ testing server so that the changes will also be there? Does the Laravel migration functions do this in a handy way? Also I know for WordPress this can be difficult so just wondering if Laravel has some handy tool that can do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the docs?  Migrations are a pretty major part of Laravel.

Comment: Migrations can be used to keep the schema in sync (tables, columns, indexes, etc) but they are not indented to keep the data in sync. It's not clear from you question which are you looking to do. Definitely have a look at the docs on migrations to see if they will meet your needs.

Comment: Sorry I should've been more specific, I want to migrate the data across from my local phpmyadmin to a production phpmyadmin. The changes I make towards one database to be finalized and moved across to another database. Think of it as making changes to code, add/commit/push to a remote git repository and the production fetching but in that kind of flow for a DB.

Answer (score 0):

Hi IneedToAskQuestions

Have a look at migrations as suggested by @Devon and @Peter

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations

I use migrations to change data in a database the same as you do in a controller.

might not be best practice but works well.

hope this helps

Comment: Hi there, So i think I should have added, "has anyone implemented or has anyone attempted to migrate changes from a local server to a remote server". So I want the data/table information to be the same in my production server and to do this smoothly and easily. 
Pretty much want the same method as when someone would update a git repository on a local device then pull changes to a remote one. Say a client changes DB in remote and needs to be followed through to the local is there a way to get those changes too and from remote to local or local to remote

Comment: The only way to do that would be to use a DB program such as HeidiSQL to transfer the data from one DB to the other but this can be problematic as production could have newer data than local and this could be overwritten